# Is it better to write my Mobx stores in a separate file or inside the React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I've seen that you can do something like this:

```
// App.js
class App extends Component {
  @observable a = 'something'

  @action change() {
    this.a = 'else'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

And I've also seen that you can write your store in a separate file (which is what I do):

```
// StoreA.js
class StoreA {
  @observable a = 'something'

  @action change() {
    this.a = 'else'
  }
}

// App.js
@observer
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.store = new StoreA()
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there any difference between these approaches? Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

You always want your store to be in a separated file, as you want to honour the principle of Separation of Concern always.

It not only make thing much more maintainable, readable down the line.

Also, when it comes to using `Mobx` and React particularly, there are many reason for separating the store from the component file.

First, the store should live independently outside of the component. You should avoiding creating a new store inside your component constructor. The problem with initialising the store inside the component constructor is that every time the component destroyed and recreated, you will end up having a new store which will lead to inaccurate behaviours.

Second, you want the store to be shareable between multiple components inside your application, otherwise you will need to passing it all around as props, which is kind of messy. In that case, you will want to have the application stores separated from the React component (otherwise you will have an import hell, and can end up in circular reference, where your files import from other in a circular way), then using `mobx-react` `Provider` and `inject` and `observer` to access to the store accross your application.

I suggest you have a look at mobx-react boiler plate to see how it's done https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate

Comment: Ohh I see! Thank you. The way I learned Mobx was creating the store in the constructor and have been doing it that way but never thought about how it could affect the behavior of the components.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually a better approach to let the store in a different file, this keeps your code cleaner and easier to read. If you don't reuse it, there are no differences, when evaluating efficiency between the two approaches, only a cleaner code.